# Как получить пользователя пригласившего нового участника в discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Мне нужно что бы при событии on_member_join бот получал того кто пригласил member-а. Мне **не нужно** считать кол-во приглашений у inviter-а, мне нужно только сам inviter.

```py
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    #тут бот должен получить того, кто пригласил member-a
bot.run("MY TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `discord` вы не можете точно узнать кто именно пригласил пользователя. К сожалению, из объекта `member` нельзя получить ссылку, по которой он зашел на сервер. Иначе все было бы довольно просто.

Вы можете дать боту разрешение ***Просматривать журнал аудита***, и посмотреть кто когда создавал ссылки-приглашения. Например, при входе нового участника (`on_member_join(member)`) можно просмотреть журнал аудита и вывести все созданные ссылки:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = member.guild

    async for entry in guild.audit_logs(limit = 100):
        if entry.action == discord.AuditLogAction.invite_create:
            print(f'{entry.user} создал приглашение: {entry.target}')
```

**Вывод:**

```
Пользователь#0000 создал приглашение: https://discord.gg/just_invite3
Пользователь#0000 создал приглашение: https://discord.gg/just_invite2
Пользователь#0000 создал приглашение: https://discord.gg/just_invite1
Пользователь#0000 создал приглашение: https://discord.gg/just_invite0
```

---

Можно получить список всех приглашений сервера, а затем получить их создателей, количество использований и [**другую информацию**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=invite#discord.Invite):

```
invites = await guild.invites()
for invite in invites:
    print(f'Ссылка: {invite.url}\nСоздатель: {invite.inviter}\nИспользования: {invite.uses}\n')
```

**Вывод:**

```
Ссылка: https://discord.gg/just_invite1
Создатель: Пользователь#0000
Использования: 0

Ссылка: https://discord.gg/just_invite2
Создатель: Пользователь#0000
Использования: 1

Ссылка: https://discord.gg/just_invite3
Создатель: Пользователь#0000
Использования: 1
```

---

Также объект приглашения можно получить по строке со ссылкой

```
invite = await bot.fetch_invite('ссылка')
```

---

**Таким образом, при входе нового участника, вы можете просмотреть вообще все приглашения, а также последние созданные и по количеству использований примерно определить по какой из ссылок зашел участник.** Но надо понимать, что точно определить нельзя, ведь он мог зайти и по ссылке недельной давности.

---

[**Здесь**](https://coderoad.ru/44594309/Discord-py-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) есть ответ от пользователя, код которого может довольно точно определять кто именно пригласил участника. Но там нужно создавать отдельный канал, файл и постоянно следить за созданием ссылок.