# Как получить id пользователя, по ссылке которого пользователь присоединился на сервер? discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Пользователь заходит на сервер discord по какой-то ссылке и бот должен выводить информацию о том, кто его пригласил. Можно ли такое сделать в discord py?

Comment: Можно только получить id пользователя, который создал приглашение с помощью ```on_invite_create```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить пользователя пригласившего нового участника в discord.py?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1317177/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-discord-py)

Comment: можно пожалуйста пример использования on_invite_create в функции on_member_join?

Comment: on_invite_create и on_member_join - это разные ивенты, их нельзя объединить в один